# Help identifying an SMT component

Tags: hardware

I have a RPi zero w that is missing a SMT component. [image: RPI zero w with missing component]

Does anyone knows what component is it and knows it specifications so I can try to solder it again?

Comment: a schematic diagram is available on the web, pleasr use it

Comment: @jsotola: It's a ***partial*** schematic. That means it's incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

It's a capacitor. I can't easily find the precise value on line. FWIW, an in-circuit test (probably inaccurate) shows ~80ufd for that part. The part also appears to be (physically) exactly the same as the capacitor just to its right in your picture.

Comment: 82u (the closest standard value) is a huge capacitance value.

Comment: It's an 0805 package and you can easily get them up to 100ufd at 6.3 volts. The value may be 47ufd in parallel with the adjacent one- I'm not sure.

Comment: You may be right - I looked at mine, but saw no markings at all. If it's in that range (~80uF), then it's likely used for energy storage - not for a timer or a filter. And if that's the case, a wide range of values would work.